# Angular Material - Side Nav

Tags: angular-material

I am using Angular Material's sidenav. I have opened the sidenav dynamically. The panel is appearing with a backdrop. User can click on the backdrop to close the sidenav. What I need is to **disable closing of sidenav on clicking of backdrop**. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XKojpE?editors=1010)

The trick is to access the backdrop element and disable pointer events on it.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" style="height:500px;" ng-cloak="" class="sidenavdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <section id="section" layout="row" flex="">
    <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">
      <div layout="column" layout-fill="" layout-align="top center">
        <div>
          <md-button ng-click="toggleRight()" ng-hide="isOpenRight($event)" class="md-primary">
            Toggle right
          </md-button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div flex=""></div>
    </md-content>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">
      <md-content ng-controller="RightCtrl" layout-padding="">
        <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
          Close Sidenav Right
        </md-button>
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
  </section>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log, $element) {
    var section,
        backdrop;

    $scope.toggleRight = function() {
      $mdSidenav('right')
        .toggle()
        .then(function () {
        $log.debug("toggle right is done");
        // Disable pointer events on backdrop
        section = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#section'));
        backdrop = section[0].children[0];
        backdrop.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      });
    }
  })
  .controller('RightCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log) {
    $scope.close = function () {
      $mdSidenav('right').close()
        .then(function () {
          $log.debug("close RIGHT is done");
        });
    };
  });
```

Comment: @camden_kid Any idea of how to use the angular-material2 side-nav bar

Comment: @indra257 Create a question and I'll try to answer it tomorrow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349956/side-nav-bar-not-working-ng-template-is-not-a-known-element

Comment: This worked great! I'm now stuck though on getting my sidenav to start up with/out the backdrop so it doesn't look weird having to wait for the sidenav to be opened before toggling the backdrop. Any ideas?