# Side Nav bar not working - 'ng-template' is not a known element:

Tags: angular-material, material-ui

I followed all the steps that are shown in the material.io

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

When I am trying to use the side-nav bar component that is shown at -https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav

I throws 'ng-template' is not a known element' error.

Comment: See AKorshunov87's comment here https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2333

Comment: I actually saw that. But I didn't get where exactly I should change to template from ng-template. Because I haven't used ng-template anywhere.

Comment: Search node_modules for any files that contain "ng-template". I suspect you may have installed an Angular 4 module.

Comment: I see "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1", in my package.json. Probably might be the issue. Can you suggest a better version to which I can rollback instead of manually updating the files in my node_modules.

Comment: Try deleting @angular/animations from node_modules and see if the error remains.

Comment: @camden_kid The issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

material.io is different than angular material: material.angularjs.org, is two different libs, so you need to install, use: `npm install angular-material`

Comment: I am following the instructions shown in their start page https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Follow this one: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started, this is the Google's Angular Material

Comment: I prefer to use material.angular.io than material.angularjs.org because I am developing my application in Angular2

Comment: oh, ok so, is just the tag on the question you need to fix... :P But sorry, I will can't help you then, I really don't know the angular-material2

Answer (score 1):

[Material-UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) is a react library that is built with Google's Material Design as the basis.

Is this issue related to MUI or only the angular library also mentioned?